# How to add next and previous on my pagination?

Tags: jquery, pagination

I have a website that has multiple cards. These cards can be filtered by the value=" " in the html. I need help trying to figure out how to add a previous and next button that keeps the logic of which filters have been selected. When the page is 1 it needs to disabled previous button and when the number is on the last number of the pagination [-1] disabled next button

Here is what i got so far [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c0fz7t5s/10/)

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="1.css">

</head>
<body>
<p>filter partner listing</p>

    <div class="tag-filters">
        <div class="checkbox">

      <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="tag-10" id="check1" />
      <label class="checklabel" for="check1">tag 10</label>

      <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="tag-11" id="check2" />
            <label class="checklabel" for="check2">Tag 11</label>

      <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="tag-12" id="check3" />
            <label class="checklabel" for="check3">Tag 12</label>

      <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="tag-13" id="check4" />
            <label class="checklabel" for="check4">Tag 13</label>


        </div>
    </div>


<br />
Pagination:
<div class="pagination">
  <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">
        <ul class="tags inline">
            <li class="tag-10" itemprop="keywords">
                <a href="/component/tags/tag/jeugdhulp" class="label label-info">Tag 10</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
        <ul class="tags inline">
            <li class="tag-10" itemprop="keywords">
                <a href="/component/tags/tag/jeugdhulp" class="label label-info">Tag 10</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
        <ul class="tags inline">
            <li class="tag-10" itemprop="keywords">
                <a href="/component/tags/tag/jeugdhulp" class="label label-info">Tag 10</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
        <ul class="tags inline">
            <li class="tag-10" itemprop="keywords">
                <a href="/component/tags/tag/jeugdhulp" class="label label-info">Tag 10</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>
<br>
<div class="col-md-4">
        <ul class="tags inline">
            <li class="tag-11" itemprop="keywords">
                <a href="/component/tags/tag/jeugdhulp" class="label label-info">Tag 11</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>
<br>
<div class="col-md-4">
        <ul class="tags inline">
            <li class="tag-12" itemprop="keywords">
                <a href="/component/tags/tag/jeugdhulp" class="label label-info">Tag 12</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>
<br>
<div class="col-md-4">
        <ul class="tags inline">
            <li class="tag-13" itemprop="keywords">
                <a href="/component/tags/tag/jeugdhulp" class="label label-info">Tag 13</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>
<br>
<div class="col-md-4">
        <ul class="tags inline">
            <li class="tag-11" itemprop="keywords">
                <a href="/component/tags/tag/jeugdhulp" class="label label-info">Tag 11</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>
<br>
<div class="col-md-4">
        <ul class="tags inline">
            <li class="tag-10" itemprop="keywords">
                <a href="/component/tags/tag/jeugdhulp" class="label label-info">Tag 10</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>
<br>
<div class="col-md-4">
        <ul class="tags inline">
            <li class="tag-12" itemprop="keywords">
                <a href="/component/tags/tag/jeugdhulp" class="label label-info">Tag 12</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>
<br>
<div class="col-md-4">
        <ul class="tags inline">
            <li class="tag-12" itemprop="keywords">
                <a href="/component/tags/tag/jeugdhulp" class="label label-info">Tag 12</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
        <ul class="tags inline">
            <li class="tag-12" itemprop="keywords">
                <a href="/component/tags/tag/jeugdhulp" class="label label-info">Tag 12</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
        <ul class="tags inline">
            <li class="tag-12" itemprop="keywords">
                <a href="/component/tags/tag/jeugdhulp" class="label label-info">Tag 12</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
        <ul class="tags inline">
            <li class="tag-11" itemprop="keywords">
                <a href="/component/tags/tag/jeugdhulp" class="label label-info">Tag 11</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>
<br>
<div class="col-md-4">
        <ul class="tags inline">
            <li class="tag-10" itemprop="keywords">
                <a href="/component/tags/tag/jeugdhulp" class="label label-info">Tag 10</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>
<br>
<div class="col-md-4">
        <ul class="tags inline">
            <li class="tag-11" itemprop="keywords">
                <a href="/component/tags/tag/jeugdhulp" class="label label-info">Tag 11</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
</div>
</body>
<style>
.pagination li {
  display: inline-block
 }
</style>
</html>
```

JS

```
var size = 5;
var $cont,chunks;
var html = '';
$(document).ready(function() {

  $cont = $('.col-md-4');
  var filterChecks = $('.tag-filters :checkbox');
  createPagination($cont);
  filterChecks.change(function() {
    html = '';
    var results = [];
    var classSelectors = filterChecks.filter(':checked').map(function() {
        return '.' + this.value;
    }).get();

    if(classSelectors.length){
      for(var x = 0; x < $cont.has(classSelectors.join()).length; x++){
        results.push($cont.has(classSelectors.join())[x]);
      }
      createPagination(results);
    } else {
      createPagination($cont);
    }
  });

  $('div.pagination').on('click', 'a', function(){
    $cont.hide();
    $(chunks[parseInt($(this).text())-1]).show();
  });

});

function createPagination(data){
  chunks = new Array(Math.ceil(data.length / size)).fill("").map(function() {
    return this.splice(0, size)
  }, data.slice());

  $cont.hide();

  for(var i = 0; i < chunks.length; i++){
    html += '<li><a href="#">'+(i+1)+'</li>';
  }

  $('div.pagination').html(html);
  $(chunks[0]).show();
}
```